# Euler Factors in Permutation Representation of Galois Group

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions

Let $k$ be a number field and $K / \mathbb Q$ a Galois extension containing $k$, with Galois group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ and let $G_k:=\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$. Let $\chi$ denote the character of the permutation representation $\rho$ of $G$ in $G/G_k$. How do I show the identity: 
$$\det[I-p^{-s}\rho(\sigma_p)|V_{p, \rho}] = \prod_{\mathfrak{p}|p} (1-N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s})$$
for every integer prime $p$? Here the determinant on the left is the Euler factor at prime $p$ appearing in the definition of the Artin $L$-function of the character $\chi$ and the product on the right is over all primes $\mathfrak{p}$ of $k$ which lie over $p$.

**Edit:** So (unaware of crossposting policies) I have already asked this question, - or rather a result that follows from the above one, - on Math Overflow (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360714/on-l-function-of-permutation-representation), but I didn't really understand a lot of the details of the arguments in the answer I received there. Furthermore, I was hoping for a more elementary proof (if possible, something that probably goes along the lines of expanding the determinant as a product of eigenvectors). Also, I would really appreciate it if I could get the details of both the ramifying primes and unramifying primes cases (since I am not very comfortable with Artin $L$-functions). Thank you.

Comment: You asked this question on MO, and it has 1 answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/360723/6518 Was that answer unsatisfactory to you?

Comment: Yeah sorry I was unable to understand most of the argument. I would have to ask questions on almost every line in order to get the argument. Asking the poster to rewrite the answer didn't seem feasible either. Also, I wanted to see if this part of the identity has a more elementary proof. So I decided to take your advice and post that here. Apologies for the misunderstanding. Should I delete one of the posts?

Comment: Well, now I don't think you can delete the MO post because it already has an answer  with an upvote.  But it would be good to clarify (in the statement of the question) here what you're looking for that's different from the answer there (something more elementary or maybe you can isolate specific details to clarify).  And maybe comment in the MO post something about this post.  (Crossposting related questions, or crossposting after not getting a satisfactory answer after a few days, is okay but you should mention the cross-posts and explain why you're doing it.)

Comment: Okay, I have added that to the above edit.

Comment: @asrxiiviii The main prerequisite is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions For $\det(I-\rho(\sigma)p^{-s}) = \prod_{C \text{ orbits of } \langle \sigma \rangle \text{ on } G/H} (1-p^{-s|C|})$ it is supposedly easy just take an example and assume it generalizes. The whole detailed proof takes 20 pages you can't expect someone will do it here.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a reference where the complete proof or at least the major steps in the proof of the identity $$\det(I-\rho(\sigma)p^{-s}) = \prod_{C \text{ orbits of } \langle \sigma \rangle \text{ on } G/H} (1-p^{-s|C|})$$ have been given?